# Button to appear above the keyboard in Flutter

Tags: flutter, mobile, flutter-layout

I have a layout the login button is at the bottom of the screen and the `TextFormField`'s are at the top of the screen. I have an issue where I want to display the button above the keyboard when it appears but I'm having difficulties doing that. I want a clean solution and not some hack, but can't seem to find one. Is using a `floatingActionButton` or `bottomNavigationBar` a solution maybe and using `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom`? Here is the code and pictures.

I have this view of the screen:

[image]

but when the keyboard appears I can't see the login button:

[image]

I wanted to put the button right beneath the password `TexFormField` after the keyboard appears.
Is there some sort a simple solution and yet not a hack for this?
Here is the code:

```
Scaffold(
            resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, // <- here I set this to false so my whole widget doesn't resize when the keyboard appears
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            body: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 48.0,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 25.0),
                      child: Form(
                        key: _loginFormKey,
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            TextFormField(
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                setState(() => email = value);
                              },
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 24.0,
                            ),
                            TextFormField(
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                setState(() => password = value);
                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 23.0, right: 24, bottom: 64.0),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: PrimaryButton(
                      buttonText: 'LOG IN',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
```

Thanks in advance for you help!

Comment: You should use a Stack widget and put your Column with your fields and your button inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you have to avoid resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false which makes your button invisible, and yes I see, you need space between edit text and button that's why you add Colum as a parent. but there is another better way to achieve this and the yes button will show in below code as you expected.

```
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body:

           Stack(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 25.0),
              child: Form(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    TextFormField(
                      onChanged: (value) {},
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 24.0,
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      onChanged: (value) {},
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.only(left: 23.0, right: 24, bottom: 64.0),
                child: SizedBox(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      child: Text("Button"),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    )),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
    );
```